# blockchain says Not enough funds

Tags: transaction-fees, blockchain.info, sending

i have 30-40 $ in my account

now i have pay for something but when i add 20$ amount i say `Not enough funds.`

and when i click on `maximum` it fill the field by 4.15$

what is the problem and how can i send money !?

[image]

Comment: About a week ago another user asked the same question on this website which I can't find. It seems there's a bug and you should contact Blockchain.info support or try reducing the network fee.

Answer (score 1):

as @mcccs mentioned i changed the network fee to a custom value and it show more fund to transfer

when i set the fee to max (137) the transferable fund is 4.15$

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can recover your funds with passphrase in other wallets